# No qualifying bean of type '....mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter' available when doing multiple mongo on Spring Boot 2.2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

So I'm following this [this guide](https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/multiple-mongodb-connectors-in-spring-boot/) to setup my Spring boot application that uses multiple MongoDB Instances (multiple Mongo Instances) everything works well until I use the `@EnableMongoAuditing` annotation. I've looked up this error and found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863819/spring-boot-mongodb-auditing-error)

> You need to pipe the MappingMongoConverter that's available in the environment into MongoTemplate as well, i.e. use new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, converter). The constructor you use is for convenience, one-off usages. We usually recommend to use AbstractMongoConfiguration in case you'd like to customize anything MongoDB specific as this makes sure the components are wired together correctly.

I cannot use the `AbstractMongoConfiguration` class since that's supposed to be for a single instance MongoDB.

I'm only using `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedData` for the auditing features.

Currently I'm initializing the `MappingMongoConverter` like this

```
@Bean(name = SecondaryMongoConfig.MONGO_TEMPLATE)
public MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoDbFactory factory = secondaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getSecondary());
    MongoMappingContext mctx = new MongoMappingContext();

    mctx.initialize();
    DbRefResolver dbRef = new DefaultDbRefResolver(factory);
    MappingMongoConverter mconv = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRef, mctx);

    mconv.afterPropertiesSet();
    return new MongoTemplate(primaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getSecondary()),mconv);
}
```

but the same error occurs `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

my question would probably be how do I setup `MappingMongoConverter` properly to fix the said error

Comment: Why don't you try to autowire it .. 

`@Autowired
private MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter;`

Comment: @amer I don't think that would work since I'm defining my own configuration, anyways, I found the solution, hope it would help other who is also using Spring with 2 mongo db instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by defining the following beans in the `MultipleMongoConfig` class file

```
@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoDbFactory factory,
                       MongoMappingContext context, BeanFactory beanFactory)
{
    context.setInitialEntitySet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Person.class, Animal.class,
            Program.class)));
    context.initialize();

    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(factory);
    MappingMongoConverter mappingConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, context);

    try {
        mappingConverter.setCustomConversions(beanFactory.getBean(CustomConversions.class));
    } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ignored) {} // Swallow error

    return mappingConverter;
}

@Bean
public MongoProperties mongoProperties() {
    // not exactly sure which property should I return
    return this.mongoProperties.getSecondary();
}
```